# How to make Stream.Write() output in UTF-8 format

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, utf-8

My issue is this:

I am generating and uploading a SQL file using ASP.NET, but after the file is saved to the FTP server, characters like ü are changed to &uul;, ø to ø and so on... How can I prevent this from happening? I don't want the file to be formatted with ASCII code, but with UTF-8.

The code that generates and uploads the file looks  like this:

```
//request = the object to be made an request out of.
Stream requestStream = request.GetReguestStream();
var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
//fileContent is the string to be saved in the file
byte[] buffer = encoding.GetBytes(fileContent); 
requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
requestStream.Close();
```

As you can see I've tried to use the `System.Text.UTF8Encoding`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Opps, the second ø there is supposed to be & oslash; without the space.

Comment: The error could be on the receiving side...

Comment: It is far more likely to be the FTP side of things causing this issue than it is with the stream writing. But you've not shown that code.

Comment: Oh, I hoped it wasn't but its propably the ftp-side that's causing the trouble then. Thanks :)

Answer (score 13):

Remember, with streams you can almost always wrap the streams as necessary. If you want to write UTF-8 encoded content you wrap the request stream in a `StreamWriter` with the correct encoding:

```
using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream, Encoding.UTF8)) {
  writer.Write(fileContent);
}
```

Since you say you're uploading to a web service be sure to set your content encoding as well. Since you haven't posted where the `request` object comes from, I'll assume it's a normal [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx).

With a HttpWebRequest you would tell the server what the content encoding is by using the `ContentType` property.

```
request.ContentType = "text/plain;charset=utf-8";
```

As others have mentioned, though, the FTP transfer itself may be breaking it too. If you can, make sure it's transferred in binary mode, not ASCII mode.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in debug and look at what gets put in 'buffer' after encoding.GetBytes() is called. This will verify if it's the rx side causing it.