# Excel Decoder Pipeline

Tags: biztalk, openxml, biztalk-2013r2, custom-pipeline-component

I've created a **Custom Pipeline** which will decode Excel file to XML file. These excel files have huge records. Excel file also has headers. I've used [OpenXML](http://www.ericwhite.com/) for processing Excel Files to XML files.

I need to optimize the memory consumption.

```
 VirtualStream Memory = new VirtualStream();
 byte[] buffer;

 buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes
               ("<ns0:Catalogue xmlns:ns0=\"" + NameSpace + "\">\r\n");

 Memory.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

 ----
 buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("</ns0:Catalogue>\r\n");
 Memory.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Comment: I suspect that using Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes you will be loading the whole message as a byte array into the buffer variable.  You probably want to stream it like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722642/how-to-make-stream-write-output-in-utf-8-format How to make Stream.Write() output in UTF-8 format

Comment: What exactly do you mean "optimize the memory consumption"?  What specific problem are you having?

Comment: How are you iterating through your data?  I assume it's not all just hard coded strings.